# Unification expression only matches on top node of tree

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I decided to turn the trigonometric identity

[image]

into a function by rewriting `unify`. So,

```
>>> trig_rule_tan = rewriterule(1 + tan(x)**2, sec(x)**2, [x])
>>> trig_rule_tan(1 + tan(x)**2).next()
```

and I get

[image]

But, as a result of unification's exact pattern matching, I can only find this function pattern if it's in at the top-most node in an expression's tree. For instance:

```
>>> list(trig_rule_tan(2 + (1 + tan(x)**2)))
```

gets no matches

[image]

How can I match a pattern mapping to a function with a `rewriterule` in a larger expression tree?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, but added my upvote to help out. One of my questions was downvoted for no reason too so its only fair :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at SymPy's FU's `TR22` function which uses the `bottum_up` function:

```
>>> eq
x/(tan(x)**2 + 1)
>>> FU['TR22'](eq)
x/sec(x)**2
```

Answer (score 0):

A stack is a good way to match parentheses. Here I have provided some code for a stack and parentheses matching.

```
class stacked(): # Nodes in the stack
    def __init__(self,obj,next):
        self.obj = obj
        self.next = next
    def getObj(self):
        return(self.obj)
    def getNext(self):
        return(self.next)

class stack(): # The stack itself
    def __init__(self):
        self.top=None
    def push(self,obj):
        self.top = stacked(obj,self.top)
    def pop(self):
        if(self.top == None):
            return(None)
        r = self.top.getObj()
        self.top = self.top.getNext()
        return(r)

def Framed(StringIn,l,r):
    s = stack()
    pairs=[]
    for n,k in enumerate(StringIn):
        if(k==l):
            s.push([n])
        if(k==r):
            q = s.pop()
            q.append(n+1)
            pairs.append(q)
    StringsOut = []
    for k in pairs:
        StringsOut.append(StringIn[k[0]:k[1]])
    return(StringsOut,pairs)

s = "(2 + (1 + tan(x)**2))"
pieces = Framed(s,"(",")")
print(pieces)
```

prints

```
(['(x)', '(1 + tan(x)**2)', '(2 + (1 + tan(x)**2))'], [[13, 16], [5, 20], [0, 21]])
```

Given this it is simple enough to iterate through the expression tree.

```
for k in pieces[0]:
    if(rewriterule(eval(k),[x]).next() != None):
        ...
```

Notice that this the framed method will not grab the whole function unless there are framing parentheses.

Hopefully this helps : )

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should have clarified, optimally I would like to be able to actually use the identity implicitly in a larger expression.